# Pasar imagen a ventana modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap

Estoy intentando abrir una ventana modal con una imagen ampliada cuando hagan click en la miniatura de la imagen del listado de productos. He conseguido la ventana modal, pero no consigo que pase el src de la imagen al modal.

Este es el código que tengo:

La imagen del listado de productos:

```
$imagen = "<img id='myImg' src='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."' width='40px' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAmpliarImagen'>"
```

La ventana modal del html:

```
<div id="modalAmpliarImagen" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <!--=====================================
                       CABEZA DEL MODAL
         ======================================-->
            <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Imagen</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <img src="" id="img01" style="width: 500px; height: 264px;" >
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Y, el js donde intento pasar el `.src` al nuevo modal:

```
$(".tablaProductos tbody").on("click", "img.myImg", function(){
var imagen = $(this).src("myImg");
        $(".img01").attr("src", 'imagen');
})
```

Se abre correctamente el modal pero la imagen no aparece.

Comment: Hola, creo que en lo que fallas es en mandarle el atributo, no veo que le estés pasando una dirección a donde tienes tu imagen, debiese ser del tipo **.attr("src", 'img/imagen.png');**

Comment: Hola Sebastian, pase la parte del php, cuando esta en el listado aparece de esta forma:

Comment: <img src="vistas/img/productos/517/746.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-id="vistas/img/productos/517/746.jpg" data-target="#modalAmpliarImagen" width="40px">

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que estás haciendo esto `$(".img01").attr("src", 'imagen');` pero el elemento `img01` no tiene clase, tiene id, por lo que debería ir así: `$("#img01").attr("src", 'imagen');`

Comment: Estás tomando correctamente la ruta de la imagen con `var imagen = $(this).src("myImg");`, pero en la siguiente línea pones la variable entre comillas y con eso ya no funciona. Quita las comillas y deja solo `$(".img01").attr("src", imagen);` para que uses la variable en lugar de cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Como ejemplo general usando javascript puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddImgDialog", function () {
 var imgsrc = $(this).data('id');
 $('#my_image').attr('src',imgsrc););
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="item_info">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg open-AddImgDialog" data-id="img/img.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Outfit</button>
</div>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img id="my_image" />
 </div>
```

Aquí data-id="img/img.jpg" es la ruta de tu imagen y añade una clase **open-AddimgDialog** en el botón

Ahora solo lo tienes que adaptar a tu código. También estoy viendo que tienes mal cerradas las etiquetas en tu código html. Revísalo. Cualquier cosa me comentas.

Comment: muchas gracias, por tu respuesta, pero en lugar de un button no puede ser sobre la imagen? quizas ese es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría, sería agregarla a la imágen "original" un `onclick`, cuando se dispare ese evento llamás a una función que maneje el `this` correspondiente, algo así como lo siguiente:

```js
function abreModalImagen(elementoImg)
{
  let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
  let imagenModal = document.getElementById("miImagenModal");
  imagenModal.src = elementoImg.src;
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<img onclick="abreModalImagen(this)" src="https://www.uba.ar/internacionales/archivos/TEST.jpg">


<div id="modal" style="display:none">

    <img id="miImagenModal">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que funcione, he tenido que cambiar el tipo imagen por button y poner de fondo la imagen

```
$imagen = "<div><button class='btn btn-default btnampliarimagen' imagen='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAmpliarImagen'><img src='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."' width='30px' /></button></div>";
```

Saludos a todos